# Rails pulling every attribute of included data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `conversations` controller which is used to pull all the conversations for a user of type `seller`.

Sellers can have `products` which can be `purchased` by `buyers` and the `product` may be free. For the list of conversations every `buyer` is tagged as a `client` or a `lead` depending on the following factors:

`buyer` purchased a paid product or subscribed to a product => `client`

`else` => `lead`

My `converastions_controller` is:

```
@conversation = Conversation.includes(:messages)
                            .get_coach_conversations(@seller)
```

My `Conversation` model has the method:

```
def self.get_seller_conversations(seller)
  @conversations = seller.conversations
                         .includes(buyer: [:purchases, :user])
                         .joins(:messages)
                         .where(messages: {only_for_buyer: false})
                         .distinct
  new.sorted_conversations(@conversations)
end

def sorted_conversations(conversations)
  conversations.sort_by { |c| c.messages.last.created_at }
               .reverse
end
```

And then in my `jbuilder` for the `seller/conversations` `index` method I have the following check to check if the `buyer` is a  `client` or a `lead`

`coach/conversations/index.json.jbuilder`:

```
json.array!(@conversations.map do |c|
  ...
  ...
  already_client: c.buyer.purchases
                         .where(seller: @seller)
                         .where('subscription = ? OR product_price > ?',
                                 true, 0)
                         .exists?
end)
```

I think I can expect this to be a slow request because I'm pulling a lot of content for the check but that `join` seems to be pulling all the attributes of every `model` which is included in the ActiveRecord request. Wondering if there's a better way to check this without needing to pull all the data.

For my includes the models have been included for the following information:

`buyer` -> `users` are connected to `conversations` through `buyer/seller` model

`purchases` -> check if `buyer` is a `client/lead`

`user` -> `buyers` `name` and `display picture`

Comment: why not store if buyer is a client/lead as a boolean in the client table?

Comment: @lacostenycoder because a buyer may be a `client` for a specific `seller` but a `lead` for a different `seller` depending on whether the `buyer` has bought any paid product from the specific `seller`

Comment: Move as much of the model logic to model methods, keep a little logic as possible in the view, especially while iterating. Hard to offer more specific help without understanding of your models and their relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you do you should move this out of the view and to a method probably on buyer. But from what we can tell, this shouldn't have to build ruby objects if it's just an active record relation.  Create a scope on buyer and pass in `@seller`

```
c.buyer.purchases
       .where(seller: @seller)
       .where('subscription = ? OR product_price > ?',true, 0)
       .exists?
```

move to model, probably Purchase?

```
class Purchase
  scope :already_client, -> (seller) {
    .where(seller: seller)
    .where('subscription = ? OR product_price > ?',true, 0)
    .exists?
  }
end
```

inside your json builder:

```
already_client: c.buyer.purchases.already_client(@seller)
```

Comment: Thank You for your help. I moved it to a scope as you suggested but I'm still looking for a way to make this more efficient. Specifically I'm unsure if the `join` is causing it to load more data than necessarry

Comment: the `.join` is just doing a sql join so it should not cause any performance issue. But you may wanna use https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet to check for N+1 queries etc. For memory concerns check out https://github.com/SamSaffron/memory_profiler and there are many others